# convert NSString to long value

Tags: ios, objective-c

Converting NSString to long value not showing proper data.

@"86200054340607012013" integerValue or intValue showing - **2147483647**

@"86200054340607012013" longlongvalue showing - **9223372036854775807**

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"86200054340607012013"];
```

showing - **9223372036854775808**

```
 NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 NSLog(@"======>%lu", [[formatter numberFromString:@"86200054340607012013"] unsignedLongValue]);
```

showing - **12413078045768810496**

What is the proper way to converting this

Comment: @Napolux Have already gave the code and output value. It's not working

Comment: Use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Your number is simply too big to fit in an `int` (32 bits) or a `long long` (64 bits): 86200054340607012013 ≈ 2^66.2. As @rmaddy mentions, you need to use something which can store a number that large (e.g. `NSDecimalNumber`)

Comment: You can't use integral type because max size of standard type is 8 bytes, but your number has 9 bytes.